# Leave axis ticks for blank treatments in ggplot r

Tags: ggplot2, label, scale, boxplot

I have a bunch of dfs with 19 treatments that I'm plotting subsets of. Trying to figure out how to leave columns for all 19 treatments in the plots, even if they have no values that are being plotted in that specific plot. Smaller reproducible example below.

```
 set.seed(3)
 df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=200))
 df$X1 <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each = 40)
 df$X2 <- runif(200,20,50)

 ggplot(df,aes(x=X1,y=X2,color=X1))+
 geom_dotplot(binaxis="y",data= df[df$X2>48,])+
 geom_boxplot(data=df[df$X2>48,],varwidth = T)
```

See how there are only columns for A,B,C,E? How do I make sure it leaves a column for D? Also, I would need it to skip a color as well so in all the different plots, A, B, C, D, and E are always consistent colors.

(it would also be preferably if I could just put the subset code in the ggplot() box if possible so I wouldn't have to write the subsets over and over again).

I tried adding

```
scale_x_date(drop=F)+
```

as a line, but it didn't change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset your data in the main `ggplot()` call. The limits of the x-axis and colours can be set manually:

```
fullvar <- unique(df$X1)

ggplot(df[df$X2 > 48,],aes(x=X1,y=X2,color=X1))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y")+
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = fullvar) +
  scale_color_discrete(limits = fullvar)
```

[image]

EDIT: Overlooked the colours question.